# What kind of diagram can I use to show method execution within a class?

Tags: uml, diagram

Is there a type of UML diagram that can be used to map out method execution within a class? The class in question has two public methods and the rest are private. I have already constructed a sequence diagram to show how interaction with the class in the context of other objects but would something like a flow diagram be appropriate to display the order of method execution within a class?

Comment: Both sequence and communication diagrams can show messages to self.

Comment: Would a sequence diagram be appropriate to show where the private "helper" methods are called within one of the public methods?

Comment: If it helps to describe your model, sure. One of the great things about UML is you get to choose what you show and what you don't and in how much detail. Often private helper methods are the sort of thing that are not shown as they are just an implementation detail but not always.

Comment: Personally, I prefer communication diagrams to sequence diagrams because they give you more control of where you put things and can accommodate multiple messages to self without getting too cluttered.

Comment: Having looked into it, I think a communication diagram might be a good way to go

Answer (score 1):

No matter your methods involved in the execution sequence belong to the same class or not you may use the sequence diagram.
If the intend is to describe the class internal heuristic than an activity diagram is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If methods invocations in your class are ordered or restricted by specific rules, you should use Protocol StateMachine. Protocol StateMachine is used, when communication protocol should be defined for interaction with owning class.
You can find detailed information in UML Superstructure document, part ProtocolStateMachine.
[UML Website](http://www.uml.org)